# All values = 's' in table in PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="netsgets";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); 
var_dump(stmt['likedFour']);
```

According to table UserData, likeFour should equal 'empty'. For some reason,  var_dump(stmt['likedFour']); is returning the string 's'. Why is this?

Edit (this is what you told me to do but it is not working):
when I run this the script stops at the var_dump.

```
require "conn.php";
echo "debug 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="netsgets";
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($row['likedFour']);
```

Comment: Because you're missing the `$` sign before `stmt`, also, you need to actually fetch the row of results from `$stmt` first

Comment: how do i fetch?

Comment: `$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc(); var_dump($row['likedFour']);` -- `$stmt` is just the `mysqli_result` object, not the actual record from your table.

Comment: @RonArel even the php manual tells you how to fetch data...

Comment: `var_dump(stmt` that right there is missing an important character. Given if that is your real code, you should be getting an `undefined stmt constant` notice.

Comment: look at the change it is still not working'

Comment: @RonArel What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any errors/warnings/notices (check the log files if you don't [have error reporting enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/3339/debugging/11471/displaying-errors))? Does the query not execute properly?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

Comment: Ah crud. You're absolutely correct. Read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) while I update my answer.

Comment: Have you updated yet?

Comment: @RonArel Yes, you need to add a call to `get_result()` to actually get to the `mysqli_result` object from your `mysqli_stmt`

Comment: Another error. Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: how can i find out on cpanel

Comment: You can call `phpinfo()` from a script, but if `get_result()` is not available, you're either running an old version prior to 5.3.0 or it's not using the `mysqlnd` driver. In that case, you should avoid selecting `*` in your queries, but instead fetch specific columns and use `$stmt->bind_result()` in combination with `$stmt->fetch()` (or switch to PDO instead of mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why does `var_dump(stmt['likedFour']);` return `'s'`:

Because you're missing the dollar sign before `stmt`, so PHP thinks you're trying to access the *constant* `stmt` instead of the *variable* `$stmt`. Since you haven't defined that constant, it will fall back to assuming you're trying to access the *string* `"stmt"`. For strings, indices must be numeric so PHP should be throwing you an "Illegal string offset" warning but will try to fix it for you by casting `'likedFour'` to an integer (which will be `0`).

Therefore, `var_dump(stmt['likedFour'])` means the exact same thing as `var_dump("stmt"[0])` to PHP, which is why you're getting the output `"s"`: the first character from `"stmt"`.

#### How to get the result you *actually* want:

You first need to retrieve the resulting rows from your query. `$stmt` is the `mysqli_stmt` object that you use to execute the query and retrieve the results, it is not actually the result itself.

To save yourself headaches in the future, always check whether your query even executed successfully before trying to retrieve the results. Then fetch the row of data:

```
$success = $stmt->execute();
if (!$success) {
    echo $stmt->error;
} else if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'No results matching that username';
} else {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    var_dump($row['likedFour']);
}
```

If you don't know how many rows will be returned, loop through them just to be safe:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row['likedFour']);
}
```